# Where should I put the GCP Pub/Sub listener code in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, startup, google-cloud-pubsub, rails-console

### Background and Setup

I have a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Pub/Sub topic called "test", for which I've published a few messages from the [GCP Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-console). I'm using a Ruby on Rails app to subscribe to this topic. From the [**Receiving Messages** section in their OVERVIEW.md documentation](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-pubsub/OVERVIEW.md#receiving-messages), I've placed that code snippet (reproduced here with brevity) in an initializer file `config/initializers/pubsub.rb`

```
require "google/cloud/pubsub"
pubsub = Google::Cloud::PubSub.new
sub = pubsub.subscription "test"

subscriber = sub.listen threads: { callback: 16 } do |received_message|
  puts "Data: #{received_message.message.data}, published at #{received_message.message.published_at}"
  received_message.acknowledge!
end

subscriber.start
sleep
```

To test that the app can receive messages, I start Rails Console and confirm that the message has arrived. Eureka!

> Data: test message I typed from GCP Cloud Console, published at 2021-04-30 16:36:42 -0400

## The Problem

Rails Console cannot receive any input. By starting the subscription listener in an initializer, I've effectively rendered Rails Console inoperable.

How can I start the subscription listener in the app without breaking the rest of the app (what is the Rails way for this scenario)?

Comment: You're calling "sleep" (which sleeps forever) in an initializer?

Comment: It's directly from the documentation they provide, with the comment "# Block, letting processing threads continue in the background".

Comment: "Block" means just that. Blocking is only useful if you're not doing anything else--it keeps the process from terminating. A Rails app does other things, like process web requests. You're putting everything but the listeners to sleep.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton, removing the `sleep` call I was able to still use Rails Console and the app worked as before. The app can still receive messages from GCP Pub/Sub and I can use the app as before.

Comment: The `sleep` is in their example so the standalone script doesn't terminate at the end, i.e., it keeps the process alive so the sub threads don't also terminate. Since Rails/console/etc. already don't exit, the `sleep` is unnecessary, but also... sleeps :)